# Center INPUT and A elements inside a DIV tag in table TD cell

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an `<input>` and `<a>` elements inside a `<div>` tag in a table `<td>` cell, and I want to center them inside that cell. How can I achieve that?
NB: I've tried many things to no avail.

```
<td>
  <div class="row">
    <a class="btn btn-warning pull-right" href="****">Edit</a>
    <form action="****" method="post" class="pull-right" onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete?');">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
    </form>
  </div>
</td>
```

[image: screenshot of current div]

Comment: try to center in the div, but not in the td.

Comment: Why are you using `<div class="row">`

Comment: don't capitalize tags like this, it is confusing to read and is not proper.

Comment: Why are you closing your form before your td tag? This code has a lot of problems and I recommend completely starting over.

Comment: You have not provided the full code required to reproduce the problem.